# Two or more than two optional parameters in django url

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

In one of my view i need two optional parameters in `url` in django. for this what i am doing is like

```
url(r'^some/?(?P<arg1>.*)?/?(?P<arg2>[0-9]+)?/$','my_view'),
```

Here when i am trying it without passing any argument in url it is working fine. If i tried to pass only one optinal argument then also this pattern works fine. 
but here when i pass the value of both the arguments in the url then it combines the value of arg1 and arg1 in arg2 like

```
/some/abcd/12/
```

and shows it like

```
 `{'arg1':'abcd/12', 'arg2':None}`
```

whereas according to my requirements it should show it

```
`{'arg1':'abcd', 'agr2':12}`.
```

help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `^some/?(?P<arg1>[\w]+)?/?(?P<arg2>[0-9]+)?/$` works for me. In the first group you only want to match letters (not the slash `/`)and not *any* character and it should at least have one character to be present. Play around with it [here](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5Esome%2F%3F(%3FP%3Carg1%3E%5B%5Cw%5D%2B)%3F%2F%3F(%3FP%3Carg2%3E%5B0-9%5D%2B)%3F%2F%24&test_string=some%2Fabc%2F&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Comment: Thanks, Seems it is working. Playing around it for sometime before accepting it as the right answer :)